# Spring boot API key setup for azure web app

Tags: spring-boot, azure, api, security, key

I have problem with API key for azure web app. I have Spring Boot application in which I set up `SecurityConfiguration` and `APIKeyAuthenticationFilter` Localy with Poatman everything works fine (I specify the header and KEY in the Postman environment). But after deployment I have `Whitelabel Error Page 403 Access Denied`.

Regarding security, in application.yaml I have

```
#Security
ecoopt:
  http:
   auth-apikey-header-name: MyAppAPIKey
   auth-header-apikey: ${env.ecoopt_apikey:DEFAULT_API_PASSWORD}
```

The values are used in `SecurityConfiguration` like this

```
@Value("${ecoopt.http.auth-header-apikey}")
private String principalRequestValue;

@Value("${ecoopt.http.auth-apikey-header-name}")
private String principalRequestHeader;
```

Again. localy using Postman everything is ok.

How to specify my environment variable which is the `ecoopt_apikey` in Azure Portal -> Configuration-> Appplication Settings...
Should it look like -  Name: `ecoopt_http_auth-header-apikey` and value: `mySecretKey`

[image]

Comment: Can you share the post outline which is working , please mask the values used...

Comment: Setting `ecoopt_apikey` as name in application settings should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whitelabel Error Page 403 Access Denied

- This error indicates that you are not authorized to access the requested resource.
- If the API key is not specified in the header or if you are unable to fetch the particular configuration from app service in your application or if the API key specified is incorrect, it leads to the 403-access denied error.

> How to specify my environment variable which is the `ecoopt_apikey` in Azure Portal

As per my understanding, you are trying to add `ecoopt_apikey` and its value as Application Settings in App Service.

- Navigate to your App Service in Azure portal.
- Go to Settings in the left pane and select Configuration.
- Click on application settings and create it by giving proper Name and Value as *key-value* pair and save it as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hei! Thanks for reply! It looks like hyphen (-) is not allowed in the name. Should I rename then to for  example:ecoopt_http_authHeaderApikey

Comment: Or there is a workaround?

Comment: you can try with underscore instead.

Comment: Thanks! I actually was going to do the same but did not know what to do with hypehn. Can you help me with this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783073/azure-pipeline-maven-goal-doesnot-use-env-file

Comment: hi @Surya, (not entirely sure waht you mean)I have accepted the answer of Pravallika KV. Posted new question in stackexchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387907/azure-pipeline-maven-goal-doesnot-use-env-file